# How to get list indices after a specific index

Tags: python, list, indices

If I have the list: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`, and I want a variable like this: `afterC = ['d','e']` - Aka, all items after 'c' get put into their own list. I've tried searching for a solution, but I can't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list` object has an `.index()` method which returns the index of a given value. This index can be used to slice the list and return the values after the given index.

For example:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

l2 = l[l.index('c') + 1:]
```

Output:

```
>>> l2
['d', 'e']
```

[Documentation linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had a feeling there was a way to get every item past a certain index, I just didn't know how. This worked for me, thanks again.